# Beamer overlay specification for description

Tags: beamer, overlays, description

I find myself using more and more using the following overlay specification for 
the `description` environment.

```
 The Animal Kingdom
 \begin{description}
   \item[Gnus]   \uncover<+->{these are large cow-like animals}
   \item[Gnats]  \uncover<+->{much smaller than gnus}
 \end{description}
```

The rationale is simple. I would like my audience to see that there two (and only two) animals in my animal kingdom. I would also like to see the names of these two. Then, I can go on elaborating, first on Gnus and then on Gnats.

I would be nice to write this without having to repeat the overlay specification
after each label, e.g., as in

```
 \begin{description}[itemuncover<+->]
   \item[Gnus]  these are large cow-like animals
   \item[Gnats] much smaller than gnus
 \end{description}
```

which would expand to

```
 \begin{description}
   \item[Gnus]  \begin{uncoverenv}<+->
     these are large cow-like animals
    \end{uncoverenv}
   \item[Gnats] \begin{uncoverenv}<+->
       much smaller than gnus
    \end{uncoverenv}
 \end{description}
```

Comment: Please post a complete MWE rather than mere fragments of code as an MWE is much more useful.

Comment: In addition to my answer below: your code using `\uncover...` does not produce the result you described for me.

Comment: You are right. I checked! Not sure if it is a bug, or the specification for the `\uncoverenv` are beyond my understanding.

Comment: My question seems to be a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154320/beamer-displaying-all-labels-in-description-environment-then-descriptions-sequ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do what you required - i.e. show all labels right away, but uncover the descriptions one by one.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcounter{curItem}
\newenvironment{descriptions}[1]{%
    \setcounter{curItem}{#1}
    \let\olditem\item%
    \renewcommand\item[2]{%
        \stepcounter{curItem}
        \olditem[##1] \mbox{}\visible<\value{curItem}->{##2}%
    }%
    \begin{description}%
}{%
    \end{description}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{The Animal Kingdom}
    \begin{descriptions}{1}
        \item{Gnus}{these are large cow-like animals}
        \item{Gnats}{much smaller than gnus}
        \item{Gants}{them}
    \end{descriptions}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is how it works: We define a new environment `descriptions` within which a normal `description` is used with items that have their visibility controlled automatically by a `\visible<#->`. The new environment takes one argument which allows to define whether the first description is uncovered immediately or not (i.e. setting the argument to `0` or `1`).* Within the new environment `\item` is redefined to take two arguments, the first being the label, the second the description. The new definition of `\item` automatically steps a counter which it then uses to control the visibility.

*Note: this argument also allows adapting the environment in the case there's other things on the slide being done with overlays. E.g. consider this:

```
\begin{frame}{The Animal Kingdom}
\only<1-2>{The more complex case of introducing the animal kingdom:}
\only<3->{They are described like this:}
\visible<2->{%
    \begin{descriptions}{3}
        \item{Gnus}{these are large cow-like animals}
        \item{Gnats}{much smaller than gnus}
        \item{Gants}{them}
    \end{descriptions}
}
\visible<2>{are the animals in the kingdom.}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: some inspiration (the use of `\mbox`) came from [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76152/beamer-definition-list-overlay-uncover-definition-later-than-entry), some more from [my answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196430/numbered-description-list-with-dot-leaders/196434#196434).

Comment: Any chance of making this cleaner, i.g., without wrapping the item's content in curly brackets.

Comment: @YossiGil none that would immediately come to mind - I'm open to suggestions if anyone has any?

Answer (score 3):

I came up with several tricks. However I'm not sure if they are robust enough. It all depends on your documents.

Firstly let me start with a very very simple example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{BEFORE}\only<+>{}
    \begin{description}[<+->]
        \item[A] aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
        \item[BB] bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb
        \item[CCC] cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc
        \item[DDDD] dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd
    \end{description}
\end{frame}
```

It has an intermediate slide:

[image]

The first trick, as greyshade just did, is to declare your own `\item` command with two arguments. By doing so you can do almost everything since you *catch* the second argument. For example in my own version:

```
\newcommand\jtem[2][{}]{\only<-.>{\item[#1]{\color{white}#2}}\only<+->{\item[#1]{#2}}}
\begin{frame}{AFTER: j}\only<+>{}
    \begin{description}
        \jtem[A] {aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa}
        \jtem[BB] {bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb}
        \jtem[CCC] {cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc}
        \jtem[DDDD] {dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd}
    \end{description}
\end{frame}
```

Notice that the separated `\only<-.>{}` and `\only<+->{}` allow the names shown in different formats before/after their descriptions appear.

[image]

Things become complicated if we want our `\item` assuming the same syntax as usual. The second trick is to typeset the name-part and the description-part alternatively. As follows:

```
\newcommand\ktem[1][]{\item<*>[#1]\item<uncover@+->}
\begin{frame}{AFTER: k}\only<+>{}
    \begin{description}
        \ktem[A] aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
        \ktem[BB] bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb
        \ktem[CCC] cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc
        \ktem[DDDD] dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd
    \end{description}
\end{frame}
```

Then we will have a sparser slide:

[image]

There is a trivial way to fix it:

```
\newcommand\ltem[1][]{\item<*>[#1]\item<uncover@+->\vspace*{-16.6pt}}
\begin{frame}{AFTER: l}\only<+>{}
    \begin{description}
        \ltem[A] aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
        \ltem[BB] bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb
        \ltem[CCC] cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc
        \ltem[DDDD] dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd
    \end{description}
\end{frame}
```

Here `16.6` is the magic number. This trick fails for different font size, different line skip, or any other reason making lines taller. (In this case, however, it looks fine.)

[image]

On the other hand if you do not have multiline description-part, simply copy the first trick:

```
\newcommand\mtem[1][{}]{\item<only@-.>[#1]\item<only@+->[#1]}
\begin{frame}{AFTER: m}\only<+>{}
    \begin{description}
        \mtem[A] aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
        \mtem[BB] bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb
        \mtem[CCC] cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc
        \mtem[DDDD] dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd
    \end{description}
\end{frame}
```

Nevertheless there could be some *shift* if the description-part is taller.

[image]

The third trick deals with colors. The point is to change the color dynamically.

```
\newcommand\ntem[1][{}]{\item[#1]\only<-+>{\color{white}}}
\begin{frame}{AFTER: n}
    \begin{description}
        \ntem[A] aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
        \ntem[BB] bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb
        \ntem[CCC] cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc
        \ntem[DDDD] dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd
    \end{description}\only<+>{}
\end{frame}
```

It fails, certainly, if you include any color-command between your words such as `\alert` or if the background is not white.

[image]

Similarly, we may also deal with opacities.

```
\newcommand\otem[1][{}]{\item[\pgfsetfillopacity{1}#1\only<-+>{\pgfsetfillopacity{0}}]}
\begin{frame}{AFTER: o}
    \begin{description}
        \otem[A] aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
        \otem[BB] bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb
        \otem[CCC] cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc cccccc
        \otem[DDDD] dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd dddddddd
    \end{description}\only<+>{}
\end{frame}
```

This is the most robust one since multiline, tall lines, and colors are harmless. The only drawback is that it may conflict with `beamer`'s own transparency-effect, e.g. section 17.6.

[image]

Last but not the least:

```
\end{document}
```